# Azure B2C dont use webview

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm pretty new with Azure and all its services and I want to use Azure B2C to provide authentication to local users and FB providers. However, I noticed that I cant use the workflow I have defined in my mobile app because Azure has a redirect URL to load a browser and show the web page defined by them or custom according to the policies defined for sign in.

I've been googling for a while but doesn't seem there's an option to have a webAPI that receives data from the mobile app and authenticate against the Azure B2C.

Does anyone know if there's a way to not use the redirect URL and use the app login workflow?

Thanks!

Comment: Will the mobile app be federating to Facebook or do you want to use Azure AD B2C to federate to it?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett the mobile app will do the request to FB. On local users, the app will send all the information to the API.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Azure AD B2C doesn't have support for this.

However, work to [support for the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow in Azure AD B2C](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13817784-add-support-for-resource-owner-password-credential) is in-progress.

This new feature will enable the mobile app to collect a user credential and POST it to the B2C tenant for validation.

Comment: interesting, I thought there was a way because I understand that thats how the real madrid app does it (https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Azure-AD-Identity/AzureADB2C). If I want to sent the data collected by the app (using the app workflow)  and sent it to the webapi service to validate it against the B2C is not possible?

Comment: 2 years old question and answer, is it possible now ?